# How to trim the video using FFMPEG library in android?

Tags: android, windows, video, ffmpeg

In My Project,uploading  the video ( duration is 10 seconds only) to amazon .So when i choose video from library of 30 seconds then i want trim the video to 10 seconds or may be less.I am using Mp4 Parser for trimming the videos but when trim the portrait video,it is converting to landscape mode and the video rotation also changes.I done lot of research in google but no solution lastly I found one solution that  FFMPEG library.In windows the ffmpeg library is not building.So what can I do now?I am new to the FFMPEG library.Please give the suggestions how to build the FFMPEG library in android.Thanks in advance

Comment: can u just upload the longer duration mp4 and then do the 'trim' on the cloud using ffmpeg instance that you install yourself on AWS/Heroku?  sample Heroku/script running in mobile upload scenario... http://pastebin.com/8SAvbdjU

Comment: I am using windows 32 bit os .I am executing the commands below sudo chmod a+x bulid_android.sh and then ./bulid_android.sh but the commands are not working in windows as well as mac os.